# Magento Rest API Product List (api/rest/products) how to know last page or product

Tags: api, rest, magento, magento-1.9

I have 32 products in my magento store.

I am fetching these products using magento rest API, like below

```
http://localhost/magento/api/rest/products?page=1&limit=10
http://localhost/magento/api/rest/products?page=2&limit=10
http://localhost/magento/api/rest/products?page=3&limit=10
http://localhost/magento/api/rest/products?page=4&limit=10
```

but if I query below url too, still it is giving product list (please not page is equal to 5)

```
http://localhost/magento/api/rest/products?page=5&limit=10
```

So is there any way to know that this is the last page or last product??

Answer (score 0):

```
            ProductWork mojProduct = new ProductWork(_url, _adminUrlPart, _consumerKey,
                        _consumerSecret, _userName, _password);


            MagentoApiResponse<IList<Product>> provera = new MagentoApiResponse<IList<Product>>();
            provera.Result = new List<Product>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {

                var filter = new Filter();
                filter.PageSize = 100; // max number
                filter.Page = i+1;
                var primio = await mojProduct.GetAll(filter);

                    if (primio.Result != null & provera != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Product item in primio.Result)
                        {
                            if ( provera.Result.Count(a=>a.entity_id == item.entity_id) == 0) { 
                                 provera.Result.Add(item);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                i = 101;
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        break;
                    }

                }



            if (provera.Result != null)
            {
                foreach (Product item in provera.Result)
                {
                  // your code here

                }

            }
```

Comment: Please do explain the answer too.

Comment: it is old, but for someone who found this question and tries blindly copying: he retrieves distinct data in first 100 pages with size of 100 (10000 products)